# Matplotlib: Display Minor Ticks and Major Ticks at the Same Axis Location

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have a plot with both Major and Minor Ticks. It is a grouped bar chart and I don't want the legend describing each category, but want each category shown in the minor ticks. Then I want each group to have the name in the major ticks.

I can do this to some extent, but the major tick seems to override the minor tick at the same location. How can I turn this off?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        0: [84, 41],
        1: [0, 0],
        2: [18.5, 3.5],
        3: [65.5, 124],
        4: [0.5, 0]
    },
    index = ['A', 'B']
)

ax = df.plot.bar(
    rot=0,
    legend=False,
    color=['gray', 'red', 'green', 'lightblue', 'darkblue',],
)

labels = df.unstack().index
label_x, label_mode = [], []

for rect, idx in zip(ax.patches, labels):
    print(rect, idx)
    label_mode.append(idx[0])
    label_x.append(rect.xy[0] + (rect.get_width() * 0.5))

ax.set_xticklabels(['A', 'B'])
ax.set_xticks(label_x, minor=True)
ax.set_xticklabels(label_mode, minor=True)
ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='minor', length=0)

ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', length=10, width=0)
```

[image: Plot with minor tick overridden]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was actually very simple. It is a single parameter `remove_overlapping_locs` passed to `xaxis` object.

```
ax.xaxis.remove_overlapping_locs = False
```

[image]

See matplotlib API changes [3.1.0](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/api_changes.html#major-minor-tick-collisions) for more details.

Comment: I'm glad this is discoverable. I [fought](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/13618#issuecomment-471071522) very hard to have a way to prevent the removal back then.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest IMHO it was completely the right decision, so thank you! It saved me a LOT of fiddling.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest. I appreciate what you did there. I'm using it right now in a different context, and I gotta say, it's one of those things you don't think you'll need until you do.