# Matplotlib wont allow minor xticklabels to be written over major labels

Tags: matplotlib, time-series

Been trying to figure this one for hours and finally thought to ask the community here:

I have a dataframe (Note the gaps in dates - eg 27 and 28 Jul are Sat and Sun so I dont have data and hence these dates dont exist in our dataset)

```
DateIndex       Actual      Prediction
0   2019-07-22  38.112534   43.821098
1   2019-07-23  38.293377   43.081688
2   2019-07-24  38.067326   42.924763
3   2019-07-25  37.193264   42.675892
4   2019-07-26  36.937077   42.324039
5   2019-07-29  36.394554   42.062973
6   2019-07-30  36.138367   41.933300
7   2019-07-31  39.152367   41.563931
8   2019-08-01  42.211578   43.121380
9   2019-08-02  42.045807   45.242599
10  2019-08-05  38.896175   45.338230
11  2019-08-06  34.495735   43.552277
12  2019-08-07  35.415005   41.371761
13  2019-08-08  34.902622   41.714703
14  2019-08-09  38.368725   41.524937
15  2019-08-12  40.403179   43.299469
16  2019-08-13  41.307377   44.358330
17  2019-08-14  37.780994   44.758350
18  2019-08-15  35.565704   42.989811
19  2019-08-16  35.942455   41.691597
```

Here is my code:

```
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (20,8)

import matplotlib.dates as mdates

# market o sets a dot at each point, x="DateIndex" sets the X axis
ax = nbpActualPredictionDf.plot.line(x="DateIndex", marker = 'o')

plt.title('Actual vs Prediction using LSTM')
ax.set_xlabel('Date')
ax.set_ylabel('NBP Prices')

# this allows a margin to be kept around the plot
x0, x1, y0, y1 = plt.axis()
margin_x = 0.05 * (x1-x0)
margin_y = 0.05 * (y1-y0)
plt.axis((x0 - margin_x,
          x1 + margin_x,
          y0 - margin_y,
          y1 + margin_y))

# hides major tick labels
plt.setp(ax.get_xmajorticklabels(), visible=False)

# get the values of DateIndex and set our own minor labels using dd-mm format
dateIndexData = nbpActualPredictionDf['DateIndex']
ax.set_xticklabels([x.strftime('%d-%h') for x in dateIndexData]);
ax.set_xticklabels(labels, minor=True)

plt.show()
```

But the chart wont allow writing minorlabels to write where the majorlabels are meant to be. even though I tried to hide them:

[image]

I stumbled upon some talk of enhancing the code to add a function: set_remove_overlapping_locs but looks like not implemented yet.

Any workarounds as right now its simply unusable as the dates move.

Ideally I would like to show the month-year on the major labels as well, so if you can help with that too.

Thanks
Manish

Comment: According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57927519/matplotlib-display-minor-ticks-and-major-ticks-at-the-same-axis-location)  the parameter should be set directly, not via a function `ax.xaxis.remove_overlapping_locs = False`

Comment: That worked out very well. Thanks @JohanC